# How can I add my own <divs> to a container dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, dynamic-arrays

I found a lot of info about this, but I haven't foundanything that could help me yet.

My problem is that I have got a div with its id and it supposes to be a container (`#cont_seguim`).
I have a menu on the right side which contains circles (made by css and filled with text), like following:

```
<div class="circle_menu b">
    <div class="text_menu n">ECO</div>
</div>
```

where b and n are the format for background and text.
When I click a circle, this one must be added to the container (notice that each circle has got its own text), but I can't get that.

I made and array and used alert() to test that click works, and it does, but append() doesn't even work to print text, and I don't know why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayS = new Array();

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".circulo_menu").click(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            alert("calling " + text);
            $("#cont_seguim").append(text);
        });
        return text;
    });

</script>
```

Thank you for your responses!

Comment: do you want to add the text or the whole circle in the `#cont_seguim` ? (*also in your html the class is `circle_menu` but in the script you use `circulo_menu`*)

Comment: hazte un jsfiddle o pega mas codigo (html/csS) pa que te podamos ayudar mejor premoh xD

Comment: I want to add the circle, but I could identify by text and then create new element, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine (*if you fix the different class name used in html vs script `circulo_menu` vs `circle_menu`*)

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/

---

To add the whole circle append the whole element and not its text by using `.append(this)`

```
    $(".circle_menu").click(function() {
        $("#cont_seguim").append(this);
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/1/

---

To add a copy of the circle, so you can add multiple of them use the `.clone()` first..

```
    $(".circle_menu").click(function() {
        var clone = $(this).clone(false);
        $("#cont_seguim").append(clone);
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/3/

---

Inside the `click` handler, `this` refers to the clicked element. And since you bind the `click` handler on the `circle_menu` element, `this` refers to that. You can use it directly for the appending or clone it to make a copy first..

Comment: Thank you very much mate. Different class name was because I tried to make it easier to understand for you, but forgave the other one :) Just one thing more: How can I display them inline? And they also leave the container :S Can I use display:inline on css as a <li>? http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/11/

Comment: @jjgonzalez make them `inline-block` and do not clone them. See my second example.. (*or your updated fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/14/*)

Comment: But I need to clone them because the circles are a menu, so I can't delete them.

Comment: I must have misunderstood.. what do you mean with "and they also leave the container" ? You want to remove them if clicked inside the `#cont_seguim`?

Comment: I have 2 containers. One of them is a menu where I click circles, the other one is where I must put circles. I mean circles leave container's height when you put 5 or 6 of them. Check it in my last fiddle, clicking 10 times on circles

Comment: do you want the container to expand its height to fit them ?

Comment: No, I want to display circles inline and only 3-4 by row, so they have to start in a new row when they reach the end of container, keeping container's height/width fixed. I don't know if I explain properly :S

Comment: @jjgonzalez, you will have to create *column* elements then, that will contain 4 elements, and they will be floated left.. See http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/16/ for an example.. (*it will still break after 7 columns*)

Comment: I have to display them horizontally. I'll try to get it tomorrow. Thank you very much!

Comment: just make the circles `inline-block` as i mentioned in my second comment.. http://jsfiddle.net/7jbUj/18/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `html()` instead of `text()`.

Answer (score 1):

unable to understand properly, hope below one can help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".circulo_menu").click(function() {
            var myText = $(this).html(); 
            alert("calling " + myText);
            $("#cont_seguim").html(myText);
        });
    });

</script>
```

make sure classname and id name will remain same as html

Comment: Ok, now I get the whole <div> of the circle pressed on the alert, nice. But I can't still append it, some idea? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:  <kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KG4uQ/)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="circle_menu b">
    <div class="text_menu n">ECO</div>
</div>
<div id="cont_seguim"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circle_menu").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).html();
        console.log("calling " + text);
        $("#cont_seguim").append(text);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( ".container" ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
```

[source](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what div should I append, because I can't identify the circle which has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#container").append($("<div/>", {id:"newID",text:"sometext"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var arrayS = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".circulo_menu").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        alert("calling " + text);
        $("#cont_seguim").append($(this).html());
    });
    return text;
});

</script>
```

By this way the clicked circle element get added to div